# Do our scriptures say anything about how to deal with an abusive parent?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, manu-smriti, manuscripts, family

Namaskaram, I am aware that our scriptures tell us to respect our parents. But what should one do is his/her father is totally horrible as a human being, who keeps on abusing and exploiting his family and others. Should the son/daughter still respect him and tolerate the abuse without speaking against the atrocious happenings?

Comment: This might be helpful : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52106/what-do-the-vedas-shastras-and-hindu-texts-say-about-ones-mother